# кнопки при клике на которые блок появляется

Tags: javascript, html

Кнопки вакансий - при нажатии кнопки разворачивается блок с текстом вакансии, повторный клик сворачивает его обратно. На самой кнопке указано название вакансии. Как сделать? Помогите!!!

Comment: По второму вашему примеру добавила html ,но блоки не активны.Если я на них нажимаю ни какой текст не всплывает,как мне его добавить и сделать чтоб разворачивался блок с текстом  вакансии. Вы меня извините,я в этом вообще профан, но мне надо это сделать

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку всплывал блок с текстом вакансии.Где мне в html после какого кода вставить этот текст чтоб он всплывал. Может я как то ни так объясняю,я не профи ))

Comment: @Юля добавьте в вопрос Вашу разметку html

Comment: <p><label for="btn1">
<div class="item"><label for="btn1"><input id="btn1" type="checkbox" /> <button>Автомеханик</button></label></label></p>
<div class="item"><label for="btn2"><label for="btn2"> <input id="btn2" type="checkbox" /> <button> Автомойщик</button></label></label></div>
<div class="item"><label for="btn3"><label for="btn3"> <input id="btn3" type="checkbox" /> <button> Администратор</button></label></label>
<div></div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Для этой задачи подойдёт старый добрый [спойлер](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80).

Вот один из простых вариантов на **jQuery**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.spoiler .button', function(){
  let parent = $(this).closest('.spoiler'),
      button = parent.find('.button'),
      content = parent.find('.content');
  if(content.css('display') === 'none') { // если контент скрыт
    content.fadeIn(); // покажем контент
    button.find('span').text('-'); // сменим "иконку" у кнопки
  } else { // если контент показан
    content.fadeOut(); // скроем контент
    button.find('span').text('+'); // сменим "иконку"
  }
});
```

```css
.spoiler .button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler .content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="button">Название вакансии <span>+</span></div>
  <div class="content">
    Описание вакансии
  </div>
</div>
```